# R: passing one value to a vector of functions

Tags: r

I have a vector of functions which I want to evaluate on the same number.

Example:

```
c=1 
functions=c(x^2,2*x,x/2)

(evaluate each function at c=1)

Desired output: c(1,2,0.5)
```

Which function would be the best to do this besides using a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please avoid declaring `c` as a variable, as it is also the name of a most common function `c()`.

Functions can not be stored in vectors,but can be stored in lists. We can loop through the list to call all functions with the desired value as a variable.

```
my_value <- 1
my_functions <- list(square = function(x) x^2,
                     dbl = function(x) 2*x,
                     half = function(x) x/2)

sapply(my_functions, \(x) x(my_value))

square    dbl   half 
   1.0    2.0    0.5
```

If we do not want names in the desired output, we can `unname()` it:

```
sapply(my_functions, \(x) x(my_value)) |>
    unname()

[1] 1.0 2.0 0.5
```

Comment: Minor quibble:  lists are vectors.  The help page `?list` describes them as "Generic vectors", and `is.vector()` returns `TRUE` for them.

Comment: That is actually true, but I think we usually think of lists when handling stored functions. And `class(c(square = function(x) x^2, dbl = function(x) 2*x))` returns `list`

Answer (score 1):

as a one-off shorthand, you could use an anonymous function:

```
c = 1
(\(x) c(x^2, 2*x, x/2))(x = c)
```